# Find word in text file even when it is wrapped to next line

Tags: grep

Is there a way to find a word in a text file which might be wrapped at an unknown position to the next line like the `table_name` in this example?

```
  'select id, field1, field2 from ta' +
  'ble_name where condition'
```

The two parts of the word are separated by a known sequence (quote, blank, new line, six blanks and quote).

It can be solved with a two step process, where the constant sequence is removed from the file before doing the search.

Am I correct that it is not possible to do it with standard grep?

Comment: With GNU grep, tr and sed: `tr -d "\n" < filename | sed -r "s/' {7}'//" | grep table_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do it with standard `grep` alone, because you cannot change the line delimiter from `\n`. Instead, you have to transform the input first as you have described.